# Enter text in popup box using Rselenium

Tags: r, rselenium

I'm trying to pull data from glassdoor website using Rselenium. I'm unable to enter email id and password in the popup window. 
This is my code. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. When I try to highlight email box, sign in button is being highlighted.

```
remDr$navigate("https://www.glassdoor.com")
webElem <- remDr$findElement("class", "sign-in")
webElem$highlightElement()
webElem$clickElement()
email <- webElem$findElement(using = "name", "username")
email$highlightElement()
email$sendKeysToElement(list("EMAIL ID")) -->Throwing Error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works with latest chrome:

```
library(RSelenium)

rD <- rsDriver()
remDr <- rD$client

remDr$navigate("https://www.glassdoor.com")
webElem <- remDr$findElement("class", "sign-in")
webElem$highlightElement()
webElem$clickElement()
remDr$setImplicitWaitTimeout()
email <- remDr$findElement(using = "id", "signInUsername")
email$sendKeysToElement(list("EMAIL ID"))

....

rm(rD)
gc()
```

Comment: I thought that I should run findElement method on remDr instead of webElem. Thanks harrsion for pointing it out. Can you pls tell some resources to learn about XPath, XML library and web scraping in R.